# Impossible to launch rails s after a scaffold regeneration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've delete scaffolded files after a renaming my Company class to Organization, using:
`rails destroy scaffold Company -f`
then
`rails generate scaffold Organization`

From now, I can't run `rails s` and have the following errors:

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.1 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:74:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Organization (NameError)
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:74:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:56:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Projects/myapp/app/admin/organizations.rb:1:in `<main>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/application.rb:130:in `block in load'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/error.rb:41:in `capture'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/application.rb:130:in `load'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/application.rb:122:in `block in load!'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/application.rb:122:in `each'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/application.rb:122:in `load!'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/application.rb:148:in `routes'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin.rb:77:in `routes'
    from /Projects/myapp/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:414:in `draw'
    from /Projects/myapp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<main>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in load_paths'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `each'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `load_paths'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:20:in `reload!'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:30:in `block in updater'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:130:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    from /Projects/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require_relative'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:in `new'
    from config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Projects/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Projects/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
MacBook-Pro-de-Benjami$
```

Any clue?

Comment: Try `rails db:migrate`

Comment: Did you define a custom Organization class? See `from /Projects/myapp/app/admin/organizations.rb:1:in `<main>'`

Comment: in the file `app/admin/organizations.rb` line 1 there is a constant `Organization` that is not initialized. try renaming your file to `organization.rb` (not pluralized)

Comment: show your code, looks like you don't have an Organization class